# Getting Artifacts on List in Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Not sure why I'm seeing this in my test project, they should be bullets:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed this in my

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```